# Unknown SSL protocol error in connection with rails app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, curl, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I upgraded my Plan on Heroku to be able to use Heroku SSL, which includes Automated Certificate Management (ACM).

Hence when i run `heroku certs:info` I get:

```
Certificate details:
Common Name(s): www.myapp.fr
Expires At:     2018-04-29 10:10 UTC
Issuer:         /C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
Starts At:      2018-01-29 10:10 UTC
Subject:        /CN=www.myapp.fr
SSL certificate is verified by a root authority.
```

or `heroku certs`:

```
Name                Common Name(s)    Expires               Trusted  Type
──────────────────  ────────────────  ────────────────────  ───────  ────
tyrannosaurs-12099  www.myapp.fr      2018-04-29 10:10 UTC  True     ACM
```

However, my app still appears as being unsecured (no https) and when I run `curl -kvI https://www.myapp.fr`, here is what I get:

```
    [2.3.4]
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.myapp.fr/
*   Trying 79.125.111.38...
* Connected to www.myapp.fr (79.125.111.38) port 443 (#0)
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.myapp.fr:-9838
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.myapp.fr:-9838
```

Any idea on How can I get my HTTPS working ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it at that time doing this: In order to force all clients to use https you will need to update your application to check for this. In Rails this is usually done by setting

`config.force_ssl = true`
in `config/environments/production.rb.`

Then wait a few minutes and it should be OK.